# Javascript to read json which is starting with some extra string

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jsonreader

I'm trying to read a json url but JSON appearing some extra string before JSON start

JSON script is like:

```
throw 'allowIllegalResourceCall is false.';
{  
   "name":"mkyong",
   "age":30,
   "address":{  
      "streetAddress":"88 8nd Street",
      "city":"New York"
   },
   "phoneNumber":[  
      {  
         "type":"home",
         "number":"111 111-1111"
      },
      {  
         "type":"fax",
         "number":"222 222-2222"
      }
   ]
}
```

I'm trying to read this JSON using this below javascript:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {           
    $('.button').click(function(){
    var ur= "http://json_url";
    alert(ur);
    alert(JSON.stringify($.getJSON(ur)));
    });
});
</script>
```

Is there any way to read this types of Json using java script/jQuery or ajax.

Comment: what error do you get ?

Comment: why do you want to stringify an already stringified json ?

Comment: I'm getting this error
{"readyStatus":0,"status":0,"statusText":"No transport"}

Comment: It was returning [object] to explore this object I'm using stringify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read this in some api doc

JSON Security String

GET requests are protected by including a security string on the line before the JSON text. The string generally looks like "throw 'allowIllegalResourceCall is false.';". To strip out this string, a regular expression should be used. For example, in python one could use:

```
json = re.sub(r"^throw.*;\s*","",json)
```

so you just need to replace the string with "" and use slashes around the regExp.

```
alert($.getJSON(ur).replace(/^throw.*;\s*/,"");
```

source : https://developers.jivesoftware.com/api/v3/cloud/rest/index.html

Comment: I'm trying 
alert($.getJSON(ur).replace("^throw.*;\s*","");
but not getting any response/alert.

Comment: Is this for JSON Hijacking? Good god, that vulnerability only affected a *few* versions of Firefox, that are no longer supported anywhere. The regex will probably work fine, but tell the API developers to code to modern standards.

Comment: No Katana, not for JSON Hijacking I'm trying to use for my own site JSON and HTML where I'm calling both are in same domain.
But I can't access Web service code, I can access JSON only.

Comment: Just a tiny remark, your "JSON" starting with "throw .." is not valid JSON. You can use [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) to verify it.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have enough points to add a comment on John Smith his answer, but he is on the right track, except from a little mistake probably because he is used to program in Python :-)

The regular expression should be: `/^throw.*;\s*/` instead of `"^throw.*;\s*"`

Instead of using double quotes, use / at the beginning and end of the regular expression.
That will do the trick.

Comment: But replace(/^throw.*;\s*/,"") will work once json is fetched, but  $.getJSON(ur) is not working so how could we apply replace(/^throw.*;\s*/,"") method on json.

Comment: Retrieve the body as a string with $.get or $.ajax first, then strip the first sentence (with replace) and use $.parseJSON to convert the remaining string into a JSON object.